# How to compile with make only a couple of previously failed targets instead of full second compile

Tags: makefile, clang, llvm, target

When I was compiling llvm and clang repo it badly hangs at a linking target close to the end(suppose due to the lack of ram) and I had to interrupt compilation with ctrl-c.But the bulk of targets were done creating a number of directories locally.Is there an option to compile only the failed targets while not doing a whole project compilation with make?

Comment: This scenario is exactly what makefiles are designed for. Since the already compiled object files are more "recent" than the source files, they will not be compiled again, unless you deliberately force those files to be rebuild (with .PHONY) whether it has been built or not.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled targets will not be recompiled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.In my case after looking up Makefile I found target 
check-all
Then make utility has checked targets and compiled only those which were not ready.
Thanks

Comment: You could've just run `make` again without any additional targets. And please mark your question as answered.